# When to separate View from ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

So I'm working on a GUI and most of it I implemented with 1 window and used the code-behind for that window to handle most of the logic. The program is very GUI driven. Say there is a combo box, if you select something from the combo box, the data drastically changes and all the other GUI boxes/labels/grids change or clear ect ect.

I'm doing a lot of refactoring and I've been aware of MVVM, but I've never really seen the need for it. I understand what and why its used, but functionality its just easier to reference all the GUI components straight from the code behind I've found.

For example...

In my main window I have

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MyTitlesUI" ItemsSource="{Binding Titles}" SelectionChanged="MyTitlesUI_SelectionChanged">
```

So the ComboBox is tied to a List Titles in my MainWindowViewModel right?
Where should MyTitlesUI_SelectionChanged event go? It needs to go in the View correct? But what if the functionality of SelectionChanged has to do with data inside MainWindowViewModel?

Say you change the selection in MyTitlesUI and now the program has to look up up that Title string in a database. All of that database functionality is in DBClass which you declare in MainWindowViewModel. How do you access that functionality? Why would you have to do this:

In main window cs:

```
private void MyTitlesUI_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   viewModel.ConnectToDataBase((string)MyTitlesUI.SelectedItem);
}
```

In MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
private SelectedTitle;
public void ConnectToDataBase(string title)
{
  SelectedTitle = title;
  DBClass myDB = new DBClass(SelectedTitle);
  .... //do stuff with myDB
 }
```

That just seems kind of unnecessary no? This is just a mild mild example of course and maybe that seems pretty clean. But if you're doing really complex back and fourth between View and ViewModel, the reference to MyTitlesUI.SelectedItem in View may be needed in ViewModel for other functions to work hence the SelectedTitle private variable.

Now you have more assignments, more variables, more functions that just call other functions than just a simple MyTitlesUI.SelectedItem to deal with.

Why not bring the DBClass reference up to the View or similar?
Especially if you're doing a lot of UI manipulation that the information inside your ViewModel will be playing with. Say once I change the selection of Title, I need graph to clear. But my graph can't clear until my ViewModel has connected to the DB or something.

I'm going to have graphs or grids defined in my View that depend on dynamically created data in my ViewModel that needs to update. And I'm trying to wrap around what needs to be in View and what needs to be in ViewModel. It seems to be not proper to reference View from ViewModel, so something like MyTitlesUI.SelectedItem can't be called in ViewModel.

EDIT:

So going back to the Selected Item example, say I have a Treeview UI item. I want to bind that to a Treeview that I don't have yet. I create the data for it procedural with DB connect. So the user selects from the combobox the Title they want. Db Connect then creates, asynchronously, a TreeviewItem in some kind of data structure.

```
private SelectedTitle;
public void ConnectToDataBase(string title)
{
  SelectedTitle = title;
  DBClass myDB = new DBClass(SelectedTitle);

  if(myDB.doneWorking)
  {
    myTreeView.ItemsSource = myDB.GetTree();
  }

 }
```

Comment: To add to @HighCore's excellent answer, you can also create your models so that changing one property value will update another. For example, if you had a `Money` property, then it could update a `Status` property to `Debit` if its value went below `0.0`. These things can also remove the need for event handlers. Even if you *really* need to handle an event, then you simply create an Attached Property to handle it for you. I tell you my friend, once you get MVVM, you'll never look back... it just fits hand in hand with WPF perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but functionality its just easier to reference all the GUI components
>   straight from the code behind I've found

**Wrong.** MVVM delivers a clean, Property-based approach that's much easier to work with than the `txtPepe_TextChanged()` winforms-like approach. Try to change the `Text` for a `TextBlock` buried deep inside a `DataTemplate` that is used as the `ItemTemplate` of a Virtualized `ItemsControl` using code behind... WPF is not winforms.

> Where should MyTitlesUI_SelectionChanged event go?

Nowhere. MVVM works best with a property/DataBinding based approach, as opposed to a procedural event-based approach.

For instance, a ComboBox-based UI that "does stuff" when the user changes the selection in the ComboBox should be defined like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyItems> MyCollection {get;set;}

    private void _selectedItem;
    public MyItem SelectedItem
    {
       get { return _selectedItem; }
       set
       {
           _selectedItem = value;
           NotifyPropertyChanged();

           DoStuffWhenComboIsChanged();
       }
    }

    private void DoStuffWhenComboIsChanged()
    {
       //... Do stuff here
    }
}
```

> Now you have more assignments, more variables, more functions that
>   just call other functions than just a simple MyTitlesUI.SelectedItem
>   to deal with.

**Wrong.** What you have now is a **Strongly Typed** property in the ViewModel of type `MyItem` that you work with instead of the horrible casting stuff `(MyItem)ComboBox.SelectedItem` or things of that sort.

This approach has the additional advantage that your application logic is **completely decoupled** from the UI and thus you're free to do all sorts of crazy stuff on the UI (such as replacing the ComboBox for a 3D rotating pink elephant if you wanted to).

> Why not bring the DBClass reference up to the View or similar?

Because **DataBase code does NOT belong into the UI**.

> Especially if you're doing a lot of UI manipulation

You don't do "UI manipulation" in WPF. You do [**DataBinding**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is a much cleaner and scalable approach.

Comment: +1 Awwww dude, you beat me to it... I was two paragraphs in, but when I saw your answer, I knew it wouldn't be worth continuing. Besides... you need the reputation. ;)

Comment: @Sheridan `you need the reputation` sounded "ok kid take the ball"... hahaha... you're just 200!! rep ahead of me. I'm going to catch up... :P

Comment: Yeah, I'm just joking obviously... I was just pointing out that I'd finally surpassed you after all this time. :) It was good to see your answer though, because I could feel one of my crazy long answers coming up... you saved me the trouble.

Comment: Thank you for the response... as bold and upfront as it was. But, what you explained about binding SelectedItem is exactly the issue I'm struggling to comprehend. You just took something that was 1 line - (MyItem) ComboBox.SelectedItem and made it into 8 with a custom set and get that didn't before. And if I went and did that with every UI item I have that has Selected Item, we're looking at a ViewModel thats easily 5-6x bigger and has that much more potential for issues than the cast on ComboBox.SelectedItem. Why is that so horrible? How is that any more "scalable" or "cleaner" as you say?

Comment: Or okay, how about MouseEnter and MouseLeave? Thats an action event, you don't bind a data variable to it. I now have to make an action handler that calls another function inside of viewModel. And what happens if when MouseEnter comes, I also want to make.... that ComboBox a pink elephant as you say. That has to go in there too. So it can't just be an event handler binded in viewModel can it?

Comment: @user999999928 it is not clear to me what you're expecting. And yes the DataBinding approach is cleaner and more scalable because 1 it decouples the application logic from the UI and 2 it removes the need to operate against the Visual Tree which is a really complicated thing you don't want to get into. This simple ComboBox case might look like it's better done in code behind but as soon as you start creating complex WPF UIs made up of hundreds of different elements you realize the Visual Tree is just too complex to deal with. That's why you need DataBinding

Comment: @user999999928 What do you want to do with MouseEnter and MouseLeave? it is unclear from  your comment, but chances are you can do what you need with a simple `Style` and some `Triggers` as  opposed to a procedural (horrible) event based approach.

Comment: One of the things I'm actually trying to achieve is a TreeView that isn't bound at the start of the program. So, say I select from the combobox the title that I want to DBconnect to. After, and only after, the DB connection is done (its asynchronous) it creates its own dictionary and within that dictionary (the title being the key), the value is a treeview. How does one bind the UI Treeview with the Treeview data in the dictionary of the Title I want, that only gets created after? Would you create a _bindingTreeView as you did with _selectedItem and leave it null until the DB connect is done?

Comment: Errr comments is hard to addendum to so it made more sense to add that to my question. I want to understand MVVM more, but find a lot of the regular tutorials and articles on it to not be as helpful in explaining why this form is more useful or in particular scenarios like this it would be beneficial or where the separation comes in. Greatly appreciate the help.